# Interpretation of AIC while modeling seasonality in ARIMA timeseries

Tags: time-series, arima, seasonality

I apologize in advance if I mess up the jargon as I am not familiar with the subject.

So I have a timeseries where I want to detect seasonality (or periodicity). The ACF of the timeseries shows a significant peak at lag `s`. I fitted the timeseries using `SARIMAX(p,d,q)(P,D,Q,s)` for different values of `p,q,P,Q` $\in$ [0,7] and calculated the AIC for each fit. It so turns out that the least AIC is for `SARIMAX(1,0,1)(0,0,0,s)`. However, when I use other period detection techniques (like DFT, Lomb-Scargle periodogram, MCMC sine fitting), I get significant periodicity at lag `s`.

[image: ACF and PACF of timeseries]

Does this imply there is no seasonality in my data? If so, then why are other methods showing periodicity?

**Additional Information:**
1. I used Monte Carlo techniques (simulating N timeseries) to obtain significance of the period in case of LSP.
2. AIC is minimum for `SARIMAX(1,0,1)(0,0,0,s)=-722` whereas the next best is `SARIMAX(1,0,1)(0,0,2,s)=-721`.
3. To check for stationarity I used `statsmodels.tsa.stattools.adfuller`. The timeseries was stationary (P-value was less than 1% critical value.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Added ACF and PACF plot. Point 3 in Additional info.